# How could Corvus Glaive so easily defeat Vision?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Vision is a super-advanced AI partially made of Vibranium and is powered by an Infinity Stone (Mind Stone). The Mind Stone was originally portrayed as a containment vessel and a power source for the Scepter. The Infinity Stone granted such diverse abilities to fire energy projectile blasts, manipulate minds, enable teleportation, perform astral projection and allow mental communication.

He has these amazing abilities and can even change his molecular density and yet he's easily defeated by being snuck up on and stabbed in the back.
**Note:** Wanda's abilities also came from the Mind Stone.

Thus, how was Corvus Glaive able to defeat Vision so easily?

Comment: Power of plot, presumably.

Comment: “No matter how subtle the wizard, a knife between the shoulder blades will seriously cramp his style.” - Brust

Comment: You can change you molecular density all you want, it doesn't make you notice people sneaking up behind you. Fairly sure there also isn't a lot of scope for applying AI to the “are aliens, whose existence I am entirely unaware of, about to stab me in the back” problem.

Comment: Related question from sister site: [Why is Vision so weak?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/89125/)

Answer (score 28):

A few things really:

- Corvus Glaive is one of the Children of Thanos, he is a powerful individual. For example, he has good combat skills being able to somewhat go hand to hand against Cap. He also seems to have a good regeneration ability considering he recovers from his stab wound pretty quickly.
- The element of surprise. This is a massive point and one you somewhat dismiss. Anyone can pretty much win any fight if they use the element of surprise. He sneaks up on Vision and stabs him in the back before he even knows what’s going on.

  For another similar example, also from *Avengers: Infinity War*, the reason Thor was able to wound Thanos with Stormbreaker whilst Thanos had the full Infinity Gauntlet was the element of surprise. He caught Thanos off guard and Thanos did not know what was coming at him.

  The element of surprise is a very effective tool, don’t dismiss it so easily.
- Corvus’ glaive is itself also very powerful on top of that as Vision himself notes.

  > **Vision:** The blade... it stopped me from phasing.
  >
  > <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

  This is further emphasised in the novelisation where it is implied that the glaive is causing a lot of stress to Vision when it is pressed against the Stone.

  > Vision lay on the ground, paralyzed temporarily, with Corvus Glaive and Proxima Midnight standing above him. Corvus Glaive had taken out the blade and was tapping it against the Mind Stone in Vision's forehead. Although the Stone was far more powerful than the blade. Vision let out a scream, feeling as if the blade was piercing his very brain. Corvus shifted his weight, replaced the blade against the Stone, and tried once more to pry it out.

Comment: Per the  Infinity War Novelisation; "_Vision lay on the ground, paralyzed temporarily, with Corvus Glaive and Proxima Midnight standing above him. Corvus Glaive had taken out the blade and was tapping it against the Mind Stone in Vision's forehead. Although the Stone was far more powerful than the blade. Vision let out a scream, feeling as if the blade was piercing his very brain. Corvus shifted his weight, replaced the blade against the Stone, and tried once more to pry it out._". The clear implication is that the spear is *special in some way*.

Comment: @Valorum Good point, Vision even states as much in the film.

Comment: Are we sure that's a proper quote? "Although the Stone was far more powerful than the blade." is a sentence fragment and also doesn't make much sense in context.

Comment: @AlexM ask Valorum, he provided the quote.

Comment: In that case I will ask @Valorum

Comment: It's a direct quote from the novelisation. I've checked two copies and it's got the same typo, with a full stop. I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be *"...Although the Stone was far more powerful than the blade* **,** *Vision let out a scream, feeling as if the blade was piercing his very brain."*